# Color the foreground of specific items in TreeViewer

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, jface

I'm trying to color the foreground of a JFace tree only if it meets the condition. I'm implementing `IColorProvider` interface and implementing `getForegroundColor(object element)`.

```
@Override
public Color getForeground(Object element)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Device device = getTreeViewer().getTree().getDisplay();
    Color color = new Color(device, 162, 82, 82);

    Schedule schedule = (Schedule) element;
    if (element instanceof Schedule)
    {
        if (schedule.getBeginEffectiveDate().equals(schedule.getEndEffectiveDate()) && schedule.getRecurrenceType().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Once"))
        {
            return color;
        }
    }           
    return null;
}
```

I tired to debug by putting the break point inside the second if, but it doesn't get into that if clause.

Comment: Shouldn't you try to cast to `Schedule` **after** you check if it's an `instanceof` it? BTW: you will have to `dispose()` the `Color` after using it.

Comment: I tried that even, it doesn't work

Comment: I didn't say it's a solution. It was just advice on good programming techniques. Which `if` doesn't your code pass? Outer or inner?

Comment: inner if clause doesn't pass

Comment: Well, how are we supposed to help you with that if we don't even know what the methods of `Schedule` are/do?

Comment: schedule is to set some records to run at our scheduled time, they can run daily or once or immediately. So Im trying to color only those schedules which are expired, this means which won't run from the current day or time.

Comment: So you're expecting us to solve a programming problem when all we have is a textual description of the code? Please post the relevant parts. Otherwise it's impossible to tell why the inner `if` clause never evaluates to `true`...

Comment: Well, I don't know what the code looks like, but based on the method names, this: `schedule.getBeginEffectiveDate().equals(schedule.getEndEffectiveDate())` doesn't make sense to me, because both use the same `schedule` instance.